# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{itn^{2}}\frac{k^{n}}{n!} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having some trouble finding the value that this infinite sum converges to $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{itn^{2}}\frac{k^{n}}{n!} $$
Is there a standard trick to solve it? The $n^{2}$ term is making it difficult for me to put into the form of a geometric sum.

Comment: Is t real? If so, the exponential term is no greater than 1 in absolute value

Comment: Convergence is trivial: $|e^{itn^2}| \le 1$ if $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and the series converges absolutely (and its absolute value is at most $e^k$).

Comment: Even if it was just $e^{tn^2}$ instead of $e^{itn^2}$ and the other commenters' points didn't apply as a result, it would still converge -- what's $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{e^n}{n!}$? Which grows faster, exponentiation or factorial?

Comment: @a52 Actually it does matter - since the exponent is $n^2$ instead of $n$, we actually have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{tn^2} / n! = \infty$ for any $t > 0$.

Comment: Yes $t$ is real. But is there a way to evaluate the sum, instead of a upper bound?

Comment: @user296602 Ahh, yes you're right. I was thinking it behaved like $e^{2nt}$ instead, for some reason. My mistake.

Comment: @99ghegh, your question is asking about convergence. Maybe change the wording?

Comment: Oh okay sorry then, what I meant was that I wanted to find the value that the sum converges to..

Comment: I wouldn't expect a closed form

Comment: What is the context? Why do you need a closed form for this series?

Comment: I was trying to compute the characteristic function..

Comment: @99ghegh, could you un-accept my answer please, I'm pretty sure it's wrong and the integrals I derived diverge. I would like to delete it and possibly work something out later. I can't delete an accepted answer